# Shower head vertical on holder. What to do?

Tags: water, bathroom

I moved to a new apartment and find it difficult to take a shower because the shower head is vertical, when I place it on its holder, so the water is sprayed horizontally. What is the best way to have it angled down so I can take a shower properly?

[image: Shower head 1]

[image: Shower head 2]

---

**Edit**: The solution suggested in [this answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/26696/1399) worked:

[image: Shower head 3]

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you can reposition the head, and its spray direction, by

- rotating the hose clamp by 90° *(shower head is now horizontal)*
- sliding the clamp further up the support *(shower head is higher)*
- twisting the shower head *(so that it sprays outward / downward)*

Comment: We have a very similar shower head mount, and twisting 90 degrees and lowering the shower head is the *default* position for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that that shower head is meant to be used by hand. The work around is fine and if it works then that is great.

Comment: You can use this both as a regular fixed shower head, as well as take it off and use by hand. This is a common setup, we have a similar one.

Comment: Ya i oddly enough saw one today at home depot. It makes sense now that you turn it sideways so the slot is on the side and then just angle up an down to get your hair wet.